# Error while installing MySQLdb for Python on Mac OSX 10.6.8 with mysql inside XAMPP

Tags: python, macos, xampp, osx-snow-leopard, mysql-python

I am trying to import MySQldb in python and call the python script from a php script in XAMPP. Here is what I did:

Environment:
1. Mac OSX 10.6.8
2. Python version 2.6 (default)[64bit]

Done so far:
1. Installed XAMPP
2. MySQL config path: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql_config
3. Downloaded MySQL-python-1.2.4b4
4. edited the site.cfg with config path for MySQL
5. Ran following commands

sudo python setup.py clean
python setup.py build

Got the following error:

```
running build
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/MySQLdb
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall - Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -pipe -Dversion_info=(1,2,4,'beta',4) - D__version__=1.2.4b4 -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/mysql - I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -c _mysql.c -o  build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/_mysql.o -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -arch i386 -arch ppc  -D_P1003_1B_VISIBLE -DSIGNAL_WITH_VIO_CLOSE -DSIGNALS_DONT_BREAK_READ - DIGNORE_SIGHUP_SIGQUIT -DDONT_DECLARE_CXA_PURE_VIRTUAL
In file included from _mysql.c:44:
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/mysql/my_config.h:1053:1: warning: "HAVE_WCSCOLL"  redefined
In file included from   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:8,
             from _mysql.c:29:
```

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/pyconfig.h:803:1    : warning: this is the location of the previous definition
    /usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/as: assembler         (/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as or /usr/bin/../local/libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as) for         architecture ppc not installed
    Installed assemblers are:
    /usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as for architecture x86_64
    /usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/i386/as for architecture i386
    In file included from _mysql.c:44:
    /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/mysql/my_config.h:1053:1: warning: "HAVE_WCSCOLL"   redefined
    In file included from         /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:8,
                 from _mysql.c:29: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/pyconfig.h:803:1:    warning: this is the location of the previous definition
    _mysql.c:3131: fatal error: error writing to -: Broken pipe
    compilation terminated.
    lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccQsr7Lk.out (No such file or directory)
    error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1

Answer (score 0):

yum install mysql-devel

pip install MySQL-python